# How to merge two data frames together with no common ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to run the sample code from here:

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/k-nearest-neighbors-in-python/

The sample data is available here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/b3nv38jjo5dxcl6/nba_2013.csv?dl=0

I'm getting an error here:

> lebron_normalized = nba_normalized[nba["player"] == "LeBron James"]
>
> Error: KeyError: 'player'

When I look at the data set, I see that `nba_normalized` doesn't have a field named `player` because `nba_normalized` is only numeric. How can I find the normalized vector for Lebron James, and based on that, find `euclidean_distances`?

Comment: Rather than an external data source, could you edit your question to include a sample of each dataframe? Perhaps `.head(10)` of each, so that we can test without downloading?

Comment: I think you may have overwrote `nba` at one point.

That dataframe (nba) should have `player` and since `nba_normalized` is a subset of that data, your filter should work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I'm pretty sure OP just overwrote `nba` at some point due to the KeyError.

To expound a bit, the masking operation isn't a merge but a True/False vector performed on a subset of a dataframe so you're less worried about joining on a key and more interested in ensuring that your dataframes are similar in composition.

```
import pandas as pd

nba = pd.read_csv('nba_2013.csv')
distance_columns = ['age', 'g', 'gs', 'mp', 'fg', 'fga', 'fg.', 'x3p', 'x3pa', 'x3p.', 'x2p', 'x2pa', 'x2p.', 'efg.', 'ft', 'fta', 'ft.', 'orb', 'drb', 'trb', 'ast', 'stl', 'blk', 'tov', 'pf', 'pts']

nba_numeric = nba[distance_columns]

nba_normalized = (nba_numeric - nba.mean()) / nba_numeric.std()

def lebron(x):
    if "lebron" in x.lower():
        return True
    return False

lebron_normalized = nba_normalized[nba.player.isin(set(filter(lebron, nba.player)))]

# Heh
print(lebron_normalized.head(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]I ran the code, and it worked for me (had to change sort to sort_values because newer version of Pandas).

The following statement is not true, and if so, then you did something wrong.

> `nba_normalized` is only numeric

When you do:

```
nba_normalized = (nba_numeric - nba_numeric.mean()) / nba_numeric.std()
```

nba_numeric is a pandas dataframe. When we do operations on dataframes, we will be subtracting and dividing the scalars for ALL columns of the data.

Comment: Yeah, I got it working and it makes sense now.  Thanks everyone!!